# Build an index based on keywords in the bibtex file using `biblatex` and `imakeidx`

Tags: biblatex, indexing, imakeidx

As a starting point, there are two examples to build indices grouped on the basis of 'authors and their titles' and 'year of published titles' [here](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/examples/22-indexing-subentry.tex).

I can also find many examples that use keywords in the `\printbibliography' command but I am not looking for that.

[This](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/latex/biblatex.def) should be the foundational source for designing the solution, but I couldn't figure it out.

If the keywords are presented in the `bibtex` as a comma-separated list, then, to organize the titles (with their cited positions in the document) on the basis of the keywords.

For example, for `mybib.bib`:

```
@article{adelson1982phenomenal,
  title={Phenomenal coherence of moving visual patterns},
  author={Adelson, Edward H and Movshon, J Anthony},
  journal={Nature},
  volume={300},
  number={5892},
  pages={523},
  year={1982},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group},
  keywords={research, experimental}
}

@article{proske2012proprioceptive,
  title={The proprioceptive senses: their roles in signaling body shape, body position and movement, and muscle force},
  author={Proske, Uwe and Gandevia, Simon C},
  journal={Physiological reviews},
  volume={92},
  number={4},
  pages={1651--1697},
  year={2012},
  publisher={American Physiological Society Bethesda, MD},
  keywords={review, experimental}
}
```

the index should look something like this:

```
experimental
    Phenomenal coherence of moving visual patterns, <position where the paper has been cited>
    The proprioceptive senses: their roles in signaling body shape, body position and movement, and muscle force, 4, 5

review
    The proprioceptive senses: their roles in signaling body shape, body position and movement, and muscle force, 4, 5

research
    Phenomenal coherence of moving visual patterns, <position where the paper has been cited>
```

Finally, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82737/165014) may help in constructing the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keywords is a special comma-separated field. We can iterate over its items with `etoolbox`'s `\forcsvlist`.

Then it is just a matter of getting the index subentries right. For that I stole the code from [`22-indexing-subentry.tex`, in particular `\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{with:year}`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/476a0dad3146012955b1f1441ffbc8f1d015ef35/doc/latex/biblatex/examples/22-indexing-subentry.tex#L68-L76).

In `index:keywords` the sole argument `#1` holds one keyword. We then index that keyword and add a subentry with the title (`\mkbibindex` field takes two arguments: the first is for sorting, the second the (formatted, if you like) printed output; the special fields `indextitle` and `indexsorttitle` are calculated automatically if they are not given explicitly in the `.bib` file).

The macro `citeindex` is changed to index the keywords. Finally, indexing of citations needs to be turned on with `indexing=cite`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, indexing=cite, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{keywords}{%
  \forcsvlist{\usebibmacro{index:keywords}}{#1}}

\newbibmacro{index:keywords}[1]{%
  \usebibmacro{index:entry}{\index}{%
    #1%
    \subentryoperator
    \mkbibindexfield
      {\thefield{indexsorttitle}}
      {\emph{\csfield{indextitle}}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\indexfield{keywords}}
    {}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{adelson1982phenomenal,
  title    = {Phenomenal coherence of moving visual patterns},
  author   = {Adelson, Edward H. and Movshon, J. Anthony},
  journal  = {Nature},
  volume   = {300},
  number   = {5892},
  pages    = {523},
  year     = {1982},
  keywords = {research, experimental},
}

@article{proske2012proprioceptive,
  title    = {The proprioceptive senses},
  subtitle = {Their roles in signaling body shape,
              body position and movement, and muscle force},
  author   = {Proske, Uwe and Gandevia, Simon C.},
  journal  = {Physiological reviews},
  volume   = {92},
  number   = {4},
  pages    = {1651--1697},
  year     = {2012},
  keywords = {review, experimental},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{adelson1982phenomenal,sigfridsson}
\clearpage
ipsum \autocite{proske2012proprioceptive,worman}
\clearpage
dolor \autocite{proske2012proprioceptive,adelson1982phenomenal}
\printbibliography
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: experimental>Phenomenal coherence of moving visual patterns>1, 3//experimental>The proprioceptive senses>2, 3//research>Phenomenal coherence of moving visual patterns>1, 3//review>The proprioceptive senses>2, 3]

Comment: Because I had multiple indices, each with a specific name, I changed `\usebibmacro{index:entry}{\index}{%` to `\usebibmacro{index:entry}{\index[name_of_my_index]}{%`

Comment: What is the use of `with` in `\DeclareIndexFieldFormat`, which is being used in the example used to index titles based on years?